# How to get access to b2c-protected resources in a desktop application that has no user?

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, azure-ad-b2c

I have Azure Function Apps protected with Azure AD B2C Authorization. But I also need to get access to some of these functions from Desktop App that has no user (without user interaction). How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Why protect it with AAD B2C if it has no user? Use the normal AAD flows for a daemon app.

Comment: The same functions can be called from the other apps with the user and need to be protected.

Comment: You need an API that supports both the B2C token issuer and the AAD token issuer. Because B2C doesn’t support client credentials, you got to use the AAD endpoint for the daemon app, since it should be using client credentials. See my sample [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/apps/blob/master/apps/spa-hellojs/source-code/.Net-Core-API-RBAC/MultiBearerAPI/Startup.cs#L36) that supports both token issuers.

Comment: If the API is behind APIM, then you can simply add more authorisation rules for each endpoint for each token issuer you trust.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are looking for a scenario like

b2c authentication--> ((Azure ad function app)(protectedbyb2c)) <--- desktop application with out user(access function app)

I see, that's currently not possible.

Please raise an [user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory?category_id=160596) and file your feedback.